# Playframework 2.3.x PostgreSQL PostGis

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.1, ebean, playframework-2.3

I'm trying to use a PostgreSQL with Postgis DB in a play! 2.3 application.
I've imported the postgis library and I'm using the postgres jdbc to access the DB.

Unfortunately, it seems that the Ebean evolution's don't persist the 'Polygon' and 'Point' from the PostGIS classes.

Any idea on how to work with PostGis and Ebeans?

Thanks

**Update:**

I'm creating a REST-ful interface, for now I'm not requiring any kind of authorization, my model and controller are the following. 
Assume that the JSON sent to the *Nodes.create()* has a field called 'localization' and is parsable to a *org.postgis.Point* class.

*models.Node.java*

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import play.db.ebean.Model;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.postgis.Point;

import play.data.validation.Constraints.Required;

@Entity
@Table(name="nodes")
public class Node extends Model{

    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Column(name = "the_geom", columnDefinition = "GEOMETRY")
    @Type(type = "org.hibernatespatial.GeometryUserType")
    public Point localization;

    @Required
    @Lob
    public String characteristics;

    @Required
    public boolean active;

    private static Model.Finder<Long, Node> find = new Model.Finder<Long, Node>(Long.class, Node.class);

    public static Node get(long id){
        return find.byId(id);
    }
}
```

*controllers.Nodes.java*

```
package controllers;

import static play.libs.Json.toJson;
import models.Node;
import play.mvc.BodyParser;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

public class Nodes extends Controller {

    public static Result read(long id){
        Node node = Node.get(id);
        if(node == null)
            return notFound();
        return ok(toJson(node));
    }

    @BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.TolerantJson.class)
    public static Result create(){
        Logger.debug("[create] Received request");

        Form<Node> form = Form.form().bind(request().body().asJson());
        if(form.hasErrors())
            return badRequest(form.errorsAsJson());

        Node node = form.get();
        node.id = null;
        node.save();

        return redirect(routes.Nodes.read(node.id));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how PostGis works, but are you using `Polygon` and `Point` from PostGis library, or you have them in your `models` package with `@Entity` annotation ?
If not, you can't use them as Ebean wants you to extend `Model`.
I'd recommend you to write your own evolutions for theses classes in `2.sql`.
If PostGis provides interfaces for `Polygon` and `Point` you can create you own classes extending `Model` and implementing each one.

Comment: I'm using Point and Polygon from the PostGis library.
I can't implement the Point and Polygon classes...

Comment: So you should write your evolutions by yourself for these two classes

Comment: The problem is that when I call save of my model, the Point and Polygon attributes are not persisted to the DB.

Comment: Show us how you organized your code like models and controller saving the data.

Comment: Ok, interesting problem. After some research, it looks like you have to wait or do differently : https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/198.